# What is the PostgreSQL equivalent to the TSQL "go" statement?

Tags: postgresql, t-sql

In T-SQL, I can state:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name 
           FROM   sysobjects 
           WHERE  name = 'tableName') 
  DROP TABLE [dbo].[tableName] 
go
```

What is the batch terminator equivalent (i.e. "go") for the following SQL command?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableName
```

Comment: I don't understand - are you looking for a anonymous code block: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpython-do.html ? Your `DROP TABLE` command looks sound on its own.

Comment: `GO` is **not** a statement - it's a **delimiter** used by SQL Server Management Studio only. It is not part of the SQL / T-SQL language

Comment: I think you want postgres's meta-command separator: Try a double back-slash "\\" instead of "go"

Comment: Postgres uses the delimiter defined in the SQL language: a `;` and you should start using that for SQL Server as well: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name; I can say `GO` finishes a scope of statement in SQL Server  and by using it local variables will dropped, Is `;` also finishes a scope like that?

Comment: [Replace the T-SQL batch terminator `GO` with the PostgreSQL batch terminator `;`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_to_PostgreSQL_Migration_by_Ian_Harding#Tables)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PostgreSQL equivalent would be:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableName;
```

So the terminator is simply the SQL standard semi-colon `;`.

Comment: I disagree that the semicolon is the equivalent of `GO`. `GO` is a batch statement terminator. Several statements may be executed within a batch, and `GO` terminates that batch. `GO` is important because it can be used to create a single script containing normal statements and statements that must be the only statement in a batch.

Comment: This is not an equivalent.  As an example, the GO command in MS SQL creates (and ends) a local scope within which variables can be declared.  The GO command will clear these declarations.

Comment: @Patrick Absolutly not ! GO act as a batch separator. When reading a lot of instrauction, a line with the GO command tell the client app to send all the commands to the SQL server, wait for the result, publish the result in the client and then continue to read the commands afeter until a new GO command is encountered. As an example in PG, how to send those two commands "ALTER SYSTEM SET wal_level = 'replica'; ALTER SYSTEM SET archive_mode = 'on';" one shot ???

Answer (score 16):

From SQL Server documentation:

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the
>   sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code
>   editor.

The syntax permits to have a number, after the keyword go, to repeat previous lines a number of times. Syntax is:

```
GO [count]
```

It separates batch. There is not an equivalent for PostgreSQL. The semicolon ends a statement, not a batch. And it is not possible to specify a number of executions.

Go references: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms188037.aspx

Answer (score 4):

It depends. `GO` is separator (delimiter) - it is special keyword that is not used in any SQL statement. PostgreSQL uses semicolon `;` as separator. In console psql you can use `\g`

```
postgres=# select 10 as a
postgres-# \g
+----+
| a  |
+----+
| 10 |
+----+
(1 row)
```

but it is not used often. Sometimes people uses `\gset` that execute SQL statement and store result to `psql` local variables. PostgreSQL can use semicolon, because PostgreSQL SQL statements has not to contain this symbol - It is different against T-SQL, because T-SQL allows some procedural constructs directly in SQL - and then T-SQL requires special separator. PostgreSQL doesn't allow it - procedural code is entered as string - and it is separated by apostrophes or custom string separators. So procedural conditional drop can looks like:

```
DO $$BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables 
               WHERE table_name = 'someTable') -- attention CASE SENSITIVITY
  THEN
    DROP TABLE "someTable"; -- attention CASE SENSITIVE syntax
  END IF; 
END $$;
```

or more simply `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS someTable` (case insensitive syntax). I used custom string separator `$$`

```
DO $$ -- DO command with start of string (started by custom separator)
...   -- some procedural code
$$ ;  -- end string by custom separator and semicolon as end of DO command
```